# Prevent babel from trying to convert resources to javascript modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

How do I prevent babel from trying to transpile resources (svg, css, ...) in an es2016 project?

---

For instance this simple project:

*src/app.js:*

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

const Obj = { name: 'obj' };
export default Obj;
```

*src/logo.svg*: regular SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image

*package.json:*

```
 "name": "test-babel",  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "description": "Please babel do not try converting svg files to js",  
  "scripts": {  
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-watch --presets es2015 src/app.js"  
  },  
...
```

*no .babelrc file, no webpack/no bundling*

---

Compilation leads to the following error:

```
$ npm run dev

> test-import@1.0.0 dev /home/user/workspace/babel
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-watch --presets es2015 src/app.js

/home/user/workspace/babel/src/logo.svg:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at babelWatchLoader (/home/user/workspace/babel/node_modules/babel-watch/runner.js:53:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/user/workspace/babel/node_modules/babel-watch/runner.js:62:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

Comment: Does your project also use webpack or some static bundling library?

Comment: no (added to the description)

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to Babel. If you import a file, Node is going to expect it to be JS, because Node doesn't know what an SVG is.

Comment: I see, but maybe there is a way to tell node or babel not to transpile svg, css... files, and import them *as is*?

Comment: No. If you want to read a file as is, use the [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) or use a build system that can handle non-js files (not sure what exists outside module bundlers).

Comment: The only somewhat related solution I've found is related to TypeScript by adding a default file to handle that type. This might apply if you're using VS Code this may apply, but not certain: https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/importing-html-files-from-typescript-bd1c50909992. They're dealing with the issue of trying to import html, but that could translate to fixing the svg issue here.

Comment: @GenericUser, Felix : thanks for your ideas, it helped me look in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Found out this plugin:   https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-import
Imported resources are inlined at compilation, if their extension is declared in .babelrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-inline-import", {
      "extensions": [
        ".css",
        ".svg"
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```

This solved my problem.